# CCMenuItemImage not responding to touches!

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

So I am adding a CCMenuItemImage to my layer like so:

```
CCMenuItemImage *pauseButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"pausebutton.png" 
                                                              selectedImage:@"pausebutton.png" // TODO add selected image
                                                              disabledImage:@"pausebutton.png"
                                                                     target:self
                                                                   selector:@selector(pauseGame:)];
        pauseButton.position = ccp(24, 292);
        [self addChild:pauseButton];
```

The problem is my pauseGame: selector is never triggered when I touch the pause button!

I have verified that the selector is set properly by doing a [pauseButton activate] (calls the selector).

Also, I have verified that my layer is responding to touches by outputting logging information in ccTouchesBegan and ccTouchesEnded.

It is also worth noting that I have sprites in my layer which register themselves for touches like so:

```
- (void) onEnter
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    [super onEnter];
}
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... You didnt add to a CCMenu...

```
CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:pauseButton, nil];
menu.isTouchEnabled = YES;
[self addChild:menu];
```

Note that your pausegame should be:

```
-(void)pauseGame:(id)sender
{
//pause game!!!
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is absolutely right. I needed to add the CCMenuItem to a CCMenu for it to register touches...